# Get the latest value of first observable when second observable emits

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui, rx.net

I have two observables in my view model, one which is an Observable for value changed by UI and another which represents Exception raised when the command fails.

I would like to create an observable which emits values from first Observable when the exception is raised. In short I would like to get following results

Marble Diagram

```
Value (Observable 1)     -- 1 --- 2 -------- 3 ------ 4 ---------------- 5 -----------

Exception (Observable 2) ----------- e ------------------------- e ------------ e --

ExpectedResult           ----------- 2 ------------------------- 4 ------------ 5 --
```

Comment: please describe it a little bit more detailed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `Sample`.

```
Value
    .Sample(Exception)
    .Subscribe(...);
```

This will get the latest value from `Value` every time `Exception` emits a signal.

Answer (score 3):

Can't really improve the 'Sample' response, but in case you wanted to build it with some of the older/original/core functions, essentially, you just need to combine a 'CombineLatest', plus a DistinctUntilChanged() on the Exception stream.

```
var values = new Subject<int>();
var exception = new Subject<Exception>();
values.CombineLatest(exception, Tuple.Create)
      .DistinctUntilChanged(t => t.Item2)
      .Select(t => t.Item1)
      .Dump();

values.OnNext(1);
values.OnNext(2);
exception.OnNext(new Exception());
values.OnNext(3);
values.OnNext(4);
exception.OnNext(new Exception());
```

Outputs:

IObservable 
2 
4

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Exception is hot or published.

```
Value.SelectMany(v => Exception
    .Take(1).Select(e => v))
.Switch();
```

This will make you get last value when there is no value between two Exception.